# How do I configure Vuetify correctly for prerender-spa-plgin?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use [prerender-spa-plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin) to generate a static site for my Vue.js project. However, as mentioned in [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158121/how-to-load-vuetify-when-using-the-prerender-spa-plugin/54262854#54262854), the JavaScript part doesn't work, meaning the static site generated has not interactivity to it. The answer provided in the above-mentioned question doesn't seem to be a valid one anymore, and I cannot find any other information regarding this.